# How do I check if a field in another activity was filled?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-fragments

Each user has its profile that is stored in a XML file linked to a Java class. But not necessarily they access this profile when they use the App, because they may just use the app without editing its profile information. I need to know if there's a way to know if a user has filled his name in his profile activity. I've thought about using Intents to pass the name variable, but since they don't necessarily open the profile file I dont know if it would work

Comment: Has the app connection with a server? How do you know how fields are filled?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not know if it's suitable for you. 
But if your goal is to know if a field in another activity was filled in Android (Java),
I think, one approach is to make a change subscription then set a variable from Application class

Like this :

```
public class YourApplicationClassname extends Application {

    private boolean isProfileNameIsEdited = false;

    public boolean isProfileNameIsEdited() {
        return this.isProfileNameIsEdited;
    }

    public void setProfileNameIsEdited(boolean isProfileNameIsEdited) {
        this.isProfileNameIsEdited = isProfileNameIsEdited;
    }
}
```

And use this as the application class in your android manifest

```
<application 
    android:name=".YourApplicationClassname" 
    ...
```

Then, when the field in the profile that you like to monitor is edited, you update the isProfileNameIsEdited attribute, and you can check in your other activity

Comment: That was what I was looking for, but yet couldn't figure out. Thanks a lot

Comment: @Mr.Spock  > Good luck, if it's what you have looking for, upvote the answer or/and accept it ;) (PS: you can as more precision if need)